# UIToolbar implemented with storyboard: how to change a button?

Tags: ios, button, replace, storyboard, uitoolbar

in my app I've implemented this toolbar within Storyboard:

[image]

As you can see, I've used four buttons and three flexible space bar button items.
For each button I created an outlet and the corresponding action and I've linked it all with Storyboard. Everything works well.

Now I want to dynamically replace a button of the toolbar.
I know that, if the toolbar itself was implemented programmatically, this can be easily achieved with the following:

```
[toolbarButtons replaceObjectAtIndex:4 withObject:newButton];
```

I'm wondering if this is possible also in my case, where toolbar and buttons are implemented via Storyboards. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
yassa

Answer (score 1):

If your UIToolbar is part of a UINavigationController then you can access it directly with `toolbarItems` property. Otherwise you would have to create a IBOutlet in your viewController and link your toolbar to it to access it.

This would be the case whether you were using a storyboard or NIB.

Answer (score 0):

If you've created outlets, Use the Outlet property to change it.

```
self.myToolBarButton = newButton;
```

where "myToolBarButton" is the name you gave that button.